# Daohub transfer ownership

Tags: the-dao, tokens, dao, dao-hub

I'm wondering how to transfer ownership of tokens in [Daohub](https://daohub.org/). I was looking at the [answer](https://forum.daohub.org/t/voting-and-ownership-transfer-in-the-dao/919/5)  to the similar question on their forums, but after further inspection of the source code, method transfer is overridden and additional checks performed:

- isFueled
- isBlocked
- transferPaidOut

The last one suggest, that only reward can be transferred, meaning ownership can not be changed, or I'm missing something?

Comment: I suppose the only thing you could to would be to give the person your private keys. So essentially your wallet and that would therefore contain those tokens. You of course would want to use escrow unless it was a friend or something.
Am I correct? My only question I guess is if you transfer the private keys. Change the password, would it be broadcast throughout the network. Or locally. The changing of the password. Regards,
Brian

Comment: Yes. You would basically sell the entire ethereum account rather than the tokens. It's risky and considering you can sell and trade in 14 more days, not worth it IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, tokens cant be transferred until the end of the Creation Phase... wait 25 more days and it will work. :-)

Comment: I have problem with transferPaidOut check. Allowed amount to transfer seems to be dependent on  balance of rewardAccount, which is only fueled in response to retrieveDAOReward being called externally.

Comment: @Ales I recommend you check out https://forum.daohub.org/t/rewards-and-exchange-traded-dao-tokens/1135, or ask a new question.